# Configuring syslogd in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, syslog

In CentOS and many other distros you can configure `syslogd` using `/etc/syslog.conf` but in Ubuntu there is no such file. Which file I should edit for configuring `syslogd` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syslog configuration in Ubuntu is usually in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

This, btw. is the setup i like to use:

```
auth,authpriv.*                                         /var/log/auth.log
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron.log
mail.=info,mail.=notice                                 -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warning                                            /var/log/mail.err
kern.*                                                  -/var/log/kern.log
*.*;mail,kern,cron,auth,authpriv.none                   -/var/log/syslog

# all warnings except auth into one file
*.warning;auth,authpriv.none                            /var/log/error.log

# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
*.emerg                         *
```

Answer (score 8):

There are syslog alternatives, primarily rsyslog.  Lucid (10.04) uses rsyslog, so you'll need to look at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d`.  I'm not sure what Precise (12.04) uses off-hand.

Here are the relevant man pages:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/rsyslogd.8.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html

Comment: for my edification, why no mention of syslog-ng?  Curious.